# What force accelerates a liquid moving in a narrowing pipe?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, acceleration, flow, bernoulli-equation

Say there is a liquid which behaves like an incompressible fluid and is flowing steadily through a pipe which is moving from a cross section of area $A_1$ to the cross section of area $A_2$, where $A_2$ is less than $A_1$. As per the continuity equation, $v_2>v_1$ and so the liquid seems to be accelerating. What force is causing this acceleration?

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Comment: [Bernoulli’s Principle on Atomic Scale](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcMgkU3pFBY) from "Physics Videos by Eugene Khutoryansky".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are right.
From continuity of the incompressible fluid you have
$$A_1 v_1 = A_2 v_2.$$
So obviously the velocity is changing.
Thus the fluid is accelerated, and therefore there must be a force causing this acceleration.
In this case the force comes from the pressure difference
between the wide and the narrow part of the pipe.

[image]
<sub>(image from [ResearchGate - Diagram of the Bernoulli principle](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Diagram-of-the-Bernoulli-principle-shows-that-as-fluid-flows-from-a-conduit-or-vessel-of_fig5_234142918))</sub>

This can be described by [Bernoulli's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle) ($p$ is pressure, $\rho$ is density)
$$\frac{1}{2}\rho v_1^2 + p_1 = \frac{1}{2}\rho v_2^2 + p_2$$

Comment: Nice answer too. Bernoulli's equation helps to understand how pressure changes.

Comment: @Bernhard actually, I think this is the cleanest explanation for me of why the _pressure_ changes with velocity.

Comment: a tapered pipe is sometimes called a *bernoulli transformer*.

Comment: @JohnDvorak As long as you are aware what the limitations are of applying Bernoulli's equation.

Comment: But why is the pressure in the narrow and wide parts different? Without that, the 'answer' is just wordplay.

Answer (score 8):

There is more mass per area behind than ahead of the constriction so since ppressure is force divided by area there develops a pressure difference

Comment: Oh c'est chouette.

Comment: No. The narrowing wall of the pipe applies backpressure.

Answer (score 6):

The simple answer is pressure.

As you state, from the continuity equation you can see that the velocity $v_2>v_1$. The next step is a momentum balance (like any balance in fluid dynamics: $\frac{d}{dt}=in-out+production$). The momentum flowing into the system is smaller than the momentum flowing out of the system ($\rho A_1 v_1^2 < \rho A_2 v_2^2 = \rho A_1 v_1^2 \frac{A_1}{A_2}$, $\frac{A_1}{A_2}>1$).

The actual force is not the pressure itself, but the pressure difference, or, actually, the difference in force, because on the left the force is $p_1 A_1$ and on the right $p_2 A_2$.

From another conceptual point. Suppose you have a garden hose. Than you have a fixed pressure drop. Now, if you squeeze it, you create a contraction. Part of the pressure drop is now needed to accelerate the fluid at the exit. The overall flowrate decreases, because you also need pressure to overcome frictional forces.